# Using pandas groupby to collapse rows into a single row?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a Pandas DataFrame object that looks like this:

[image]

Using the first two rows as an example:

I'd like to transform the first two rows into one row like this:

**Elm Water Sombrero | KHAKI | XS/S, M,L**

The closest that I have gotten is this:

```
products = products.groupby(['title', 'color'])['size'].apply(' '.join)
```

```
title               color      
ELM WATER SOMBRERO  BLUE           XS/S M/L
                    KHAKI          XS/S M/L
MYLA SWIM BOTTOM    BLACK          XS S M L
                    NEON PINK      XS S M L
                    TURQUOISE      XS S M L
MYLA SWIM TOP       NEON ORANGE    XS S M L
                    NEON YELLOW    XS S M L
                    WHITE          XS S M L
Name: size, dtype: object
```

This correctly joins the sizes but unfortunately it produces a Series of form (title, color): joinedSizes and is missing a label for the sizes.

I'm experienced with Pandas but despite reading over multiple groupby tutorials on the internet I can't seem to crack this one, I'd really appreciate some help from the community!

Comment: I think you just want `.reset_index()` on your resulting series.

Comment: Please include your data as text, [not as a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11301900). It would also be good to have more of your code. See: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Wow so I guess all I had to do was call reset_index(). Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `agg` and `as_index=False` to the `groupby`

```
products = products.groupby(['title', 'color'], as_index=False)['size'].agg(' '.join)
```

Comment: I believe you would need to use a multicolumn index on the groupby result for this to work properly, i.e. `[['size']]` instead of `['size']`

Comment: @alkasm: It works. I tested it. Let's ask OP try it on his dataset  :)

Comment: Indeed it should work on the same format as OP has. However if you had two columns instead (i.e. drop the color column), the single column selector won't work (you'll get the column names joined instead). The multicolumn selector will work in both cases. Honestly I have no idea why this happens lol

Comment: @alkasm: yelp. I have been gotten hit by these behaviors so I know. I guess it probably is a bug. However, I use it as quirks when I need :)